# Optimal Play in a Dice Casino Game. Why doesn't an integral work here?

Tags: integration, optimization, summation

Suppose you are playing a game where you have 20 sided die whose "1 side" is facing up initially. There are 100 rounds.

Each round you can either:

Roll the die OR
Gain an amount of money equal to the number on the die.

For example if I rolled a 20 on the first roll I would simply take the 20 dollars for 99 rounds, never rolling again.
How would you optimize your rolls to get the highest payout on average?

To be more precise: How long do I roll for and at what minimum die number do I stop?

The average payout for a given roll $n$ where $1 \leq n \leq 20$ is given by:

(Rounds - average number of rolls to get to $n$ or higher) * average earning

Rounds = 100

average # rolls = $\frac{20}{20-n+1} $

average earning = $\frac{\sum_{k=n}^{20}k}{20-n+1}$

Giving us: $$(100 - \frac{20}{20-n+1}) * \frac{\sum_{k=n}^{20}k}{20-n+1}$$

Now, because we are taking the average amount of rolls over a long period of time, as we will be playing multiple times, this means we should be able to create a continuous, differentiable function f(x) from $1 \leq x \leq 20$.

My first intuition was to simply

$$(100 - \frac{20}{20-x+1}) * \frac{\int_{x}^{20}ndn}{20-x+1}$$

and find $x$ where $f'(x) = 0$, and then find the global maximum from that.

However, these expressions are not equivalent. Where did I go wrong and what is the proper way to "smoothify" this function?

Comment: "We will be playing multiple times" is how you might justify a frequentist approach to probability. But it does not change the interpretation of an **individual** game, which still has a discrete distribution. Why would you **want** an integral?

Comment: Problem is complicated.  The basic idea is that on roll $~a ~: a \in \{1,2,\cdots,99\},~$ if you roll $~b~$ or better, then you accept the score of $~b~$ on all subsequent rolls.  The tricky part is that the *optimum* value of $~b~$ will be a function of $~a.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be intutively clear that the dice roll you'll wait for will be very high, not much below the maximal $20$. For example, waiting for $16$ or better will on average take 4 rolls. Even if it takes $10$ rolls, it is worth waiting for it over a first round roll of say $10$, because the additional value of $6$ we get in the last $90$ rolls outweighs the lost $100$ we would get from the initial $10$ in the first 10 rolls where we wait for the $16$ or better to appear (and gain no money).

But in that range of $n$, your approximation

$$S(n):=\sum_{k=n}^{20} k \approx \int_x^{20} ndn =: I(x)$$

is very bad!

We have $S(20)=20$, but $I(20)=0$; $S(19)=39$, but $I(19)=19.5$; $S(18)= 57$, but $I(18) = 38$. a.s.o.

The reason is that the discrete sum $S(n)$ has $20-n+1$ summands, but the integral only integrates similar values over a length of $20-n$. This can best be seen for $n=18$, where both the sum and the integrand have an average value of $19$, but the sum has $3$ terms but the integeral only intergrates over a length of $2$.

So my suggestion would be to replace the integral with the exact polynomal that describes $S(n)$:

$$S(n)=\sum_{k=n}^{20}k = \frac{20+n}2(20-n+1).$$

That even simplifies your whole expression and reveals (which isn't that surprising) that if you wait for a roll of $n$ or higher, your avarage earning is $\frac{20+n}2$.

As has been remarked in the comments, your strategy of choosing an $n$ and then waiting for rolling it (or better) isn't the best possible. If in an unlucky scenario you haven't rolled your $n$ in the first $99$ rounds, are you really going to roll in round $100$ again (guaranteeing that you will not win anything), or will you simply not roll and take the money indicated by the dice at that point?

In other words, the nearer you come to the end of the game without having rolled your number, the lesser a roll you should accept in the next round and stay with it. That's because the fewer rounds are remaining, the bigger the relative effect of not taking money now and the possibility to roll even lower in the next few rounds is vs. simply taking what has been rolled last round.

What exactly the cut-off values are can be determined by simple programming with e.g. a spreadsheat program (with a $100\times 20$ table of data) by going backwards. On round $100$, your choice is clear, you take money according to what the dice shows. So if the dice shows $n$ in the $1\ldots 20$ range, you get $n$ dollars, which you put into the corresponding columns  of row $100$.

On turn $99$, if you roll the die, you get the average payout of turn $100$ (which is $10.5$). If you don't roll, you get twice the ammount of what the die shows. So you should roll the die if it shows $1$ to $5$, but keep it if it shows $6$ or more. That means your expected payout for when you are at round $99$ is $10.5$ if the die shows $1-5$ from the last round and $2x$ if it shows an $x$ ($x \ge 6$).

This repeats for all "previous" turns. For each of the $20$ possible values ($x$) the dice can show at the start of that round, you can either keep it, or reroll.

If you keep it, your expected earnings for the remaining part of the game are $x$ from this round and the expexted earnings when $x$ appears at the start of the next round (which you already calculated, as we are going backwards).

If you roll the dice this round, you get nothing this round and the avergage of the $20$ possible value you could roll from the next round onwards.

You can calculate both values, and choose the strategy that gives you the higher expected value.

If you (or better your program) do that, you can simply look at the expected value when having the dice show $1$ at the start of round $1$. It will be higher than what you calculated with your formula, but I assume only a little. That's because $100$ rounds is a long game for such a mechanism where each random roll has "only" $20$ values.

For example, not throwing a $20$ in $100$ rolls has probability $\approx 0.62\%$. That means just waiting for your number is likely to succed very very often and the additional gain from accepting a lower number late in the game is (on averge) small.

If the game was shorter (say only $10$ or $20$ rounds) the effect if the refined strategy would be more profound.

Comment: follow up: am I correct in generalizing that for a a given roll n at a specific round r, we are comparing if (the roll value) times (the number of rounds left) is greater than the (average payout from 1 to 20) times (the number of rounds left after rolling)
giving:  $$10.5\left(100-r\right)<n\left(100-r+1\right)$$

$$\frac{10.5\left(100-r\right)}{\left(100-r+1\right)}<n$$

keep when this expression is true, and roll when false?

Answer (score 1):

#### My attempt to solve the problem

To address the problem, I've adopted a more intricate approach that relies less on intuition. I'll outline this approach to provide clarity on what you try to smooth here.

For simplicity I only consider strategies of the form "Wait for the first $n$ or higher to occur and accept the score for all subsequent rolls" where $n=1, \dots, 20$. Let's denote the payoff of the strategy "Wait for the first roll to be at least $n$ and accept this score for all subsequent rounds" as $X_n$.

It is our aim to maximize expectation. Then, by Law of total expectation,
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_n] = \sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac{20-n+1}{20} \bigg(\frac{n-1}{20}\bigg)^{k-1} \mathbb{E}[X_n \vert \text{first score greater or equals $n$ in the $k$-th round}]. $$

If the first score greater or equals $n$ occurs in the $k$-th round, the payoff for all previous rounds is zero, as we kept rerolling until this round. For the subsequent $100-k$ rounds, we accept the score of that round and receive the corresponding payout. Denote the score of that particular round by $Y$, then:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_n \vert \text{first score greater or equals $n$ in the $k$-th round}] \\ = (100-k) \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y \, \vert \, Y \geq n] \\ = (100-k) \frac{\sum_{j=n}^{20} n}{20-n+1} \\ = (100-k)\frac{(n+20)}{2}.$$

Altogether,

$$ \mathbb{E}[X_n] = \frac{(21-n)(n+20)}{40} \sum_{k=1}^{100} \bigg(\frac{n-1}{20}\bigg)^{k-1}(100-k).$$

#### Why smoothing is not unique

You attempted to express the expression for $\mathbb{E}[Y \, \vert \, Y \geq n]$ using an integral. Essentially, this involves the desire to smooth the discrete probability distribution of a 20-sided dice roll, represented by variable $Y$. To achieve this, the goal is to redistribute probability mass to neighboring regions around a given value. However, it's crucial to note that there isn't a universally preferred method for this smoothing process. The choice of smoothing technique will impact the optimal parameter, as probability mass allocation can vary across different choices.

#### What to do instead

To maximize your expression, there are two approaches. Firstly, you could evaluate the expression for various values of $n$ and determine which one yields the maximum result. Alternatively, you can optimize the expression over the set ${1, \dots, 20}$ using continuous analysis techniques. More precisely, seek an explicit representation for $\sum_{k=n}^{20}k$. This expression is continuous with respect to $n$ on $[1,20]$. Notably, its derivative is positive for values less than $\frac{\sqrt{205}+105}{5} \approx 18.14$ and negative for values greater than this threshold. Consequently, the only potential candidates are $n=18$ and $n=19$. Upon a brief examination, it becomes evident that $n=18$ is indeed the optimal choice.

A short final remark: Questions of this nature are frequently encountered in interviews in quantitative finance.